# Spritekit, do copying an existing node and initializing a new node cost comparable computational power?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am a Spritekit beginner (beginner programmer perhaps), right now practicing writing a dodge bullet game. A question arose, right now many nodes with similar properties (bullets) are needed, I figured out two ways to do so

```
func spawnBullet() {
    let bullet = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius:30)

    //set other properties here...

    self.addChild(bullet)
}
```

another is:

```
var bulletNode: SKShapeNode?

func setBulletProperty() {

    let bullet:SKShapeNode? = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30)

    //set other properties here...

    bulletNode = bullet
}

func spawnBullet() {
    let newBullet = bulletNode.copy() as! SKShapeNode
    self.addChild(newBullet)
}
```

“set property here...” can be rather long. So my question is, in terms of computational cost, does the two version above use similar amount resources?

To me intuitively, second version cost less, since setBulletProperty only need to be called once. And copy() is somehow easy than spawnBullet() of version one.

if they do cost differently, will the costs be comparable? or they will cost significantly different if, say, 30 nodes are added in one sec?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: The copy part will be creating a new node, and setting the properties on the new node to be the same as the existing node. So I think they would be of similar speed, but you can always time it to be sure.

Comment: Seriously - don't worry about it. Write the code that most clearly expresses what you are doing and then, if it starts running slowly, investigate the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I forget where I read this, and how I learnt this, but do remember that Copy is MUCH faster. I used it, and proved it to myself. So much so that it's good for making complex particle systems and other things that would be heavy if simply instantiating.